Ford 5.4 2V ... Fluid around intake manifold... what could this be?
I have a Ford van -- 1998 E150 V8 5.4.
No oil or on ground or loss of coolant that I notice, but...
under the doghouse, around the intake manifold, I am seeing evidence of some kind of leak.
Can anyone tell what it might be or where it might be coming from?  Coolant? Oil?  I don't understand how oil could be leaking from an intake manifold... but I also don't understand much.
Anyways... here are some photos:
Full View of Doghouse:

Middle:

Right side:

Left side:


Are you familiar with exhaust gas recirculation, EGR? Emissions control uses methods of positive crankcase gases from combustion blowing past piston rings, creating pressure in the crankcase. This pressure of combustion, burned fuel and oil, is fed back into the intake air system for reburning. Combustion byproducts coat the entire interior of intake manifolds, back of throttle bodies or carburetors, building up as......sludge over the years. Fresh and burned motor oil may be what you're seeing as oil tends to spread.
